# how can i authenticate users out of rails with authlogic?

Tags: ruby, authlogic

In my system, users registering via rails website. I have to authenticate users from a custom application server written in ruby.

error messsage:

```
You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects (Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError)
```

Comment: Please tag Rails questions correctly.

Answer (score 6):

From: http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/authlogic

```
require "authlogic/test_case" # include at the top of test_helper.rb
setup :activate_authlogic # run before tests are executed
UserSession.create(users(:whomever)) # logs a user in
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this first:

```
Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
```

Comment: At UserSessions Controller?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this error using advice from user239662's answer (it wasn't clear to me hence I'm posting this solution).  My Cucumber step definition now looks like this:

```
When /^I am logged in as "(.*)"$/ do |user|
  @current_user = User.make!(:username => user)
  require 'authlogic/test_case'
  activate_authlogic
  @current_session = UserSession.create!(@current_user)
end
```